Python to Pyspark migrated code is running too long
I have a python script to predict an output using Logistic regression. Input file has only 40k entries with 10 columns which is relatively a small dataset for spark engine. This code is part of a pipeline where the preceding codes runs for 1-2 hours (in python) and the end result is to predict an outcome using logistic regression. The Python prediction script runs only for 11 seconds however the spark code for the same runs for more than an hour. This is strange!
Below is a portion of the script in Python and Pyspark. In pyspark part of the python code runs for more than 1 hour but displays the results that's expected.
##Python script 
import scorecardpy as scard
import statsmodels.api as stm

logistic_model_pickle= "read pickle file for model"
data = scard.woebin_ply(input, pickle_file)
column_woe = [x for x in data.columns if x.endswith('woe')]
data['pred_prob'] = logistic_model_pickle.predict(stm.add_constant(data[column_woe]))



##Corresponding pyspark script

data = "same input file form python code in parquet format"
group_column =  ['ID', 'DATE', 'Segment']
original_columns = data.columns

schema = StructType([
  StructField('ID', IntegerType(), True), 
  StructField('DATE', DateType(), True), 
  StructField('Segment', IntegerType(), True),
  StructField('col1_woe', DoubleType(), True), 
  StructField('Col2_woe', DoubleType(), True), 
  StructField('Col3_woe', DoubleType(), True), 
  StructField('Col4_woe', DoubleType(), True), 
  StructField('Col5_woe', DoubleType(), True),  
  StructField('Col6_woe', LongType(), True),
  StructField('Col7_woe', DoubleType(), True)])


@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def func_woe(data_frame):
  model1 = "read a pickle file from blob storage"
  dataframe_woe             = scard.woebin_ply(data_frame, model1 )
  return dataframe_woe

data_woe = data.groupBy(group_column).apply(func_woe)
data = data.join(data_woe, on = group_column, how='left')  
display(data) ## This is where the code takes more than 1 hour where the same line in python runs for 1 second.

The woebin_ply function returns a dataframe with woe values for all columns (ranging from Col1 till Col7) and so I used a Panda_udf with Grouped_map. Can anyone advise where things might go wrong?

give me the sample data including target column you trained the model.

It’s official data so I can’t share it in internet. But I have shared its Schema in my example.

There're a couple of optimizations you can apply to speed up things in your pyspark code, namely optimizing the Pandas UDF to consider vectorized operations (run all at once not row-by-row), distribute the model across the workers (broadcast), and tweak spark configurations.

Load model outside pandas udf and broadcast it: By loading it outside of the UDF and applying broadcast from Spark Context (sc.broadcast(model)) you ensure that the model is effectively distributed in all workers.

import pickle 

model_path = "Add your path here"

with open(model_path, 'rb') as f:
    logistic_model_pickle = pickle.load(f)

broadcast_model = sc.broadcast(logistic_model_pickle) # This will broadcast to the workers


Use vectorized operations inside the UDF: UDFs (user defined functions) are like black boxes and they do not leverage Spark native optimizers (e.g. Catalyst Optimizer), therefore make sure the code applied is performant. Convert your pandas inputs / output as pd.Series, leverage .loc, .iloc and similar operations to improve the inner efficiency of yoru code.

@pandas_udf(result_schema)
def predict_udf(*cols):
    
    df = pd.concat(cols, axis=1) # Get all the columns requires as a DataFrame
    
    df_woe = scard.woebin_ply(df, broadcast_model.value) # Apply the woebin_ply using model previously broadcasted
    
    # Vectorized Operation instead list comprehension -> way more efficient
    column_woe = df_woe.columns[df_woe.columns.str.endswith('woe')]
    
    # Run prediction given broadcasted module
    df_woe['pred_prob'] = broadcast_model.value.predict(stm.add_constant(df_woe[column_woe]))

    # Return values as series
    return pd.Series(df_woe['pred_prob'])


Spark Dataframe Optimizations (Checkpointing, Cache, Repartition, and Windows): Here you will need perform some experimenton in order to callibrate effectively which tecnique will be useful or not. Before running the join I'd checkpoint your dataframe in order to cut down the execution plan, probably this will improve the performance as well. Additionally, you can also repartition your dataframe before the model predict in order to improve efficiency. Generally speaking big dataframes would require a high number of partitions whereas small dataframes a lower one. Caching might also be helpful if you are applying repeated transformations over the same dataframe. Lastly, groupBy usually forces a shuffle, try using Window for better grouping performance if possible.

    save_path_here = "" 
    
    data = data.repartition(4) # --> added a really small number, but it depends on how many cores you have and size of your data
    
    data.cache()
    data.take(1) # --> Force Caching
    
    data_woe = data.groupBy(group_column).apply(func_woe)
    
    # Checkpointing: cut-down execution plan
    data_woe.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(save_path_here) 
    data_woe = spark.read.format("delta").load(save_path_here)
    
    data = data.join(data_woe, on = group_column, how='left')  
    data.display()
    data.unpersist() # --> Remove from caching



(Extra) Why not trying with pure pandas instead? If the dataframe is small enough you can avoid the spark distribution overhead and do it with vectorized operations in pure pandas and switch back from a Spark dataframe when neeed. Don't forget to enable pyArrow for better serialization:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")




Thanks for your inputs. I’ll try this and get back to you.
Since all preceding codes were running on pyspark I wanted to try with pandasUDF here.  It’s now taking too longer so I have used the original python code for daily processing.

Anytime @Ash please let me know whether worked properly or not

Another idea you can discover that has worked nicely for me:
You're applying a function that you previously wrote in Pandas on a grouped PySpark dataframe, so you can consider the applyInPandas function. I took it from an example of a Databricks ML course and it seems to be quite efficiënt. They use it to apply Scikit-Learn models on PySpark Dataframes.
Also avoids the use of UDF's, which I personally prefer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
